# How to translate "ON/OFF"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

I need to translate a software interface into German.

What is the most concise and still effective translation for "ON/OFF"?  The action (verb) to switch on/off is "notify"

Comment: I hope you don't translate the interface itself but only the manual and things visible to clueless end users. Translated interfaces between software components are frustrating. Imagine: German MS-Excel uses German function names by default. It's horrible.

Comment: If you don't know how to translate on/off, you may want to stay away from translating to German...

Comment: Robert is absolutely right: **Do not try to translate ANYTHING that is supposed to be read by users (customers) into any language, if you have to ask what so simple words like »on« and »off« are in that language.** Keep your hands off translations if you don't speak the taget-language at minimum at level C1! For definition of level "C1" read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages#Common_reference_levels

Comment: The quality target for a translation should be "average German understands the translated interface better than the original interface". That's a high target. If you're not 100% sure you can achieve that, you might not bother translating.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Even if your German is perfect, you can't just translate "On/Off" because the correct translation will depend on the exact situation. Plus it is conceivable that there is little space in the user interface, so you need something really short.

Answer (score 3):

Amongst the many [possible translations for *on / off*](http://www.dict.cc/?s=on%20off) we'd use

> **EIN / AUS**

in case a switch in a technical or software context was meant.

Comment: So, why didn't you suggest "an" instead of "ein"?

Comment: @Em1 *ein* appears to be used more often in this context.

Comment: Any evidence for this? Because I don't think so.

Comment: @Em1 e.g. this [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=einschalten%2C+anschalten&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceinschalten%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canschalten%3B%2Cc0) that is also supported by the DWDS word frequency charts for [einschalten](https://www.dwds.de/wb/einschalten) vs. [anschalten](https://www.dwds.de/wb/anschalten). Regionally *an-* may be more frequently used but in general *ein-* is used approx. 10 times more often.

Comment: @Takkat, when talking about frequency, may can take advantage of Google Trends also: https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=DE&q=ein%2Faus,an%2Faus, which confirms your proposal

Comment: I don't think this is any evidence. We're not talking about "einschalten" vs "anschalten" (and even then, we would have to look at context and not only comparing the number of words), but about the short "on/off" switch that appears on an user interface in software. Many of the possible contexts of "ein- bzw. anschalten" are just dismissed by this fact and we're limit to just a few possible meanings that are not even covered by the words in common books (like (de)activating a listener/observer, for instance; related to computers only). And that already makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

For user options also possible:

> - aktiv / inaktiv [Straßenbeleuchtung, Solarstromeinspeisung]
> - aktiviert / deaktiviert [Alarmanlage]
> - aktivieren / deaktivieren

Text *on / off* must not necessarily refer to a toggle button. For a mere user information [coming from a sensor] I would prefer *aktiv / inaktiv* to *ein / aus*.

**Sample aktiv / inaktiv**

[image: sample aktiv/inaktiv]

**Sample aktiviert / deaktiviert**

2 apps are running. App 1 checks periodically if app 2 is still alive. If app 2 has crashed app 1 can restart it. 
So the settings of app 2 may contain:

[image: sample aktiviert/deaktiviert]

**Sample aktivieren / deaktivieren** (house security)

[image: sample aktivieren/deaktivieren]